# Xamarin Google Tag Manager Integration

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

My goal is to integrate the GTM (Gootle Tag Manager) SDK in a Xamarin.iOS app without having to use Firebase.

Problem:
The instructions for integrating GTM from the [Xamarin component store](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleiostagmanager) only show how to integrate via Firebase. Whereas Google provides 2 options, including [one that does not require Firebase](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/).

Additionally the GTM Xamarin component is missing types and methods provided by the original Google GTM SDK. Ex: `TAGManager, TAGContainer`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have figured this out. Hopefully this could help someone hoping to do the same. We currently use TagManager with Google Analytics in our Xamarin apps.

You need to install specific version of Google TagManager via Nuget and latest Google Analytics for your Xamarin.iOS app.
Packages currently used:
Xamarin.Google.iOS.Analytics - v 3.17.0.1
[Xamarin.Google.iOS.TagManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.TagManager/) - v 3.15.0.5

These packages should allow for the objects you are looking for TAGManager, TAGContainer to be found.

Follow this tutorial from a colleague of mine if you want Enhanced Ecommerce: 
[How To Implement Google Tag Manager Enhanced Ecommerce iOS in Xamarin](http://www.bigmegacode.com/xamarin-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-ios/)